# How to hide the UITabBar and show UIToolBar?

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, objective-c-category

I read several answers to this question but couldn't figure out how to do it. I'm using Xcode 4.2 with ARC and no storyboards.

I'm developing an app based on the TabBar application template and extended it to contain 4 `UITabBars`. I'm not using `UINavigationController` but instead using `UINavigationBar` next to the status bar. When the app is loaded with the first tab shown, I have a button on the `UINavigationBar` and when I press it, I want to hide the `UITabBar` and instead show the `UIToolBar` at the same location where the `UITabBar` was located.

I tried to hide and show using the hidden property (hiding the `UITabBar` and showing `UIToolBar`). What happens is the `UITabBar` is hidden but the `UIToolBar` is shown above the location where the `UITabBar` was shown before. This looks ugly and I want it to be shown at the very bottom of the screen.

I think I can't use `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` as I don't use a `UINavigationController` but instead using Navigation bar directly.

Also, I want to revert back to showing the `UITabBar` and hide the `UIToolBar` when pressing the same button on the `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: can you share your code and can you post how do you create the "frame" for the UIToolBar?

Comment: The UITabBar is created programatically (being done by the UITabBar application template). I used IB to drag the UIToolBar onto the xib file and added a IBOutlet in the .h file and synthesized in the .m file on the UIViewController shown in the first tab. Using the synthesized property, I was able to show the toolbar. I'm not using any code to manipulate the frame of the toolbar. Please advise.

Comment: I don't know the overall context for this, but does presenting a `modal UIViewController` over your tabBarController be a better more logical user experience?

Comment: Thanks to all for your comments. I would prefer to use the same UIViewController to hide/show the UIToolBar. The reason being, I'm manipulating a label in the center of the UIViewController when the user presses the "Start" button on the navigation bar. Is it not possible to hide/show the UIToolBar from within the same view controller? All I need is to move the UIToolBar to the very bottom of the screen where the UITabBar was shown. Btw, does this violate Apple's HIG?

Comment: Can somebody assist me on this? I'm really stalled on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if my idea would work for your scenario. Here it is...

but before, just let me tell you that **hiding `UITabBar`, unlike hiding `UINavigationBar` is not animated**. So to me, hiding tabBar is not a user-friendly approach, unless you create your own subclass of `UITabBarController` that animates hiding the `UITabBar`.

You can use `presentModalViewController:animated` and `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` methods. The viewController that is being shown modally can have a `UINavigationBar`, it pops out from the bottom of the screen and covers the `UITabBar` with animation.

Hope that helps.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: You're the man. I followed what you said which definitely makes sense. The app now looks cool and runs very good. Thanks for the tip though!